# Error when I try to fit keras model in Google Colab with images on Google Drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm new in machine learning and machine vision. So I trained a model with 903 grayscale images (size was 640:480) and everything was good. But now when I try to fit model with 4203 grayscale images (size is 80:120) it gives me error:

```py
Epoch 1/10
 14/132 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2:42:35 - loss: 0.0103 - accuracy: 0.9955
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b5674ef6abfe> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(ds_train, epochs=10, verbose=1)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown:  /content/anime2/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ML/All_train_cut/forward_1170.png; Input/output error
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_4]]
  (1) Unknown:  /content/anime2/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ML/All_train_cut/forward_1170.png; Input/output error
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_445]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

I use Google Colab and get images from Google Drive
Here is how my model looks like and how I get the images:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

from tensorflow import keras

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = "2"

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/anime2')

directory = '/content/anime2/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ML/All_train_cut/'
df = pd.read_csv(directory + 'train.csv')
file_paths = df['file_name'].values
labels = df['label'].values

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_paths, labels))

def read_image(img_path, label):
  image = tf.io.read_file(directory + img_path)
  image = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=1, dtype=tf.float32)
  return image, label

ds_train = ds_train.map(read_image).batch(32)

image_w = 80
image_h = 120
batch_size = 32

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input((image_h, image_w, 1)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(5),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=[
          keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    ],
    metrics='accuracy'
)
model.fit(ds_train, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Link to Google Drive folder with images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Uj7YhqyDJiq5d2ufQbI_MXe7T2-fOlk9?usp=sharing
But all images are correct. And every time it gives me an error in different images. So I really don't understand what is wrong... Thanks!

Comment: what's the shape of /content/anime2/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ML/All_train_cut/forward_1170.png when you read it?

Comment: the shape is (120, 80)

Comment: it seems weird that your image needs a float 32 for the color of the pixels, but I don't think it's the source of your problem

Comment: you could try using the default uint 8

Comment: it didn't help :)

Comment: ok, I read some opened issues on github about the problem. At least Im not the only one with the error. So the issue link: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/510. And as I understood I have to wait about day and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the error now. I just waited one day before trying again. So here is some posts from Google Colab GitHub issues #510:

1. I am an occasional Colab Pro/Drive (paid subscription) user, maybe using a 2-3 times a month. I have this problem about half the time over the last few months. I'll come back later and run the same code and it will work fine...
2. Inferring from what others have posted, it seems that Google puts some read/write caps on Drive, and if you exceed them, you'll get this error unless you wait for 24 hours without reading or writing. It would be nice if the error message were more specific.
3. yup, even with google colab pro and having 100gb storage in drive if this error occurs(in my case this only occur if I factory reset the runtime and run colab again) then you have to wait 1 day to reset the quota. This might be a cloud issue here they have to "empty" the virtual storage and machine used to compute large files.